# javascript/jQuery VAR maxium length

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to google it, but all key words references to funtions or solutions working with content of variable.

My question is simple.
If variable represents a number,

```
var a = 1;
```

what is its max bit length? I mean, what highest number can it contain before buffer overflow happens?
Is it int32? Is it int64? Is it a different length?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin

Comment: it won't buffer overflow  in js...

Comment: You mean "double precision floating point overflow" (or "double overflow"), or "integer overflow" (when a number stops being treated as an integer and starts being a double) - both of these pertain to JavaScript's numbers. You can't have a buffer overflow without a buffer - it's a completely different concept. (@dandavis: If you have an [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer), you can have buffer overflow in JS.)

Comment: Numbers are not stored as integers in JS. Every number is a IEEE 754 floating point number.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: But even with floats, there is a threshold where `x + 1` is guaranteed to work the way one imagines integers should work - that's what I was referring to. (Also, the result of bit operations are true integers, and if you are specifically talking about storage, `Uint32Array` stores true integers; I agree that is not really relevant here, but "Every number is a IEEE 754" is not 100% correct.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [the spec says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type), numbers in JavaScript are [IEEE-754 double-precision floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format):

- They're 64 bits in size.
- Their range is `-1.7976931348623157e+308` through `1.7976931348623157e+308` (that latter is available via `Number.MAX_VALUE`), which is to say the positive and negative versions of `(2 - 2^-52) × 2^1023`, but they can't perfectly represent all of those values. Famously, `0.1 + 0.2` comes out as `0.30000000000000004`; see [*Is floating-point math broken?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)
- The max "safe" integer value (whole number value that won't be imprecise) is 9,007,199,254,740,991, which is available as `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` on ES2015-compliant JavaScript engines.
- Similarly, `MIN_SAFE_INTEGER` is -9,007,199,254,740,991

Answer (score 2):

[Numbers](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.19) in Javascript are [IEEE 754 floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) double-precision values which has a 53-bit mantissa. See the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number):

> **Integer range for Number**
>
> The following example shows minimum and maximum integer values that
>   can be represented as Number object (for details, refer to ECMAScript
>   standard, chapter 8.5 The Number Type):
>
> ```
> var biggestInt = 9007199254740992;
> var smallestInt = -9007199254740992;
> ```